# How to check if value is equal to string in array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to check if the value: **diam-mm** exist in array, if the value not exist do something.

A array can have multiple properties, property name is: [PropertyType]->[Name]

i thought i loop to the properties and check if diam-mm value exist, else do something but because of the loop he does import the value mutliple times instead of one time.

Example of one array with properties:

```
[2] => Array
        (
            [PropertyType] => Array
                (
                    [Guid] =>
                    [DataType] => Text
                    [Name] => diam-mm
                    [Unit] => 
                )

            [BooleanValue] => 
            [DateTimeValue] => 
            [NumericValue] => 
            [TextValue] => 400
            [XmlValue] => 
            [UrlValue] => 400
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [PropertyType] => Array
                (
                    [Guid] => 
                    [DataType] => Text
                    [Name] => lengte-mm
                    [Unit] => 
                )

            [BooleanValue] => 
            [DateTimeValue] => 
            [NumericValue] => 
            [TextValue] => 2000
            [XmlValue] => 
            [UrlValue] => 2000
        )
```

Comment: You need to use recursion if the array is nested more than 1 array deep and you don't know how many layers it might have.

Comment: Can you give a tip how i can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
   for ($i=0; $i <count($array) ; $i++) { 
     if($array[$i]['PropertyType']['Name']=="diam-mm"){
        // your code
     }
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if an array key matches a value you can do so using simple variable assignment. However you would need to loop through each array index item and enumarate the loop based on it's iteration.

To create the loop I would suggest using `count` to count the amount of items in the array. We will assign the result to a variable :

```
$count = count($my_array);
```

Do keep in mind that `count` only counts the number of items based on their actual count, not their array index. This means that an array with indexes starting from zero which has an index of 0-30 would return 31 as the result of `count` because `count` counted the zero index as an actual count value.

To fix this we need to subtract 1 from the result of `count` :

```
$count = $count - 1;
```

Then we can use the count as the number of repeats in a `for` loop. Where the variable `$i` represents the iteration that the loop is going through :

```
//Loop through each array index
for($i=0; $i <= $count; $i++){
    //Assign the value of the array key to a variable
    $value = $my_array[$i]['PropertyType']['Name'];
    //Check if result string contains diam-mm
    if(str_contains($value, 'diam-mm'){
        echo 'The value matches!';
    } else{
        echo 'The value does not match!';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function, i hope this answer your question...

```
function array_recursive_search_key_map($needle, $haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $first_level_key=>$value) {
        if ($needle === $value) {
            return array($first_level_key);
        } elseif (is_array($value)) {
            $callback = $this->array_recursive_search_key_map($needle, $value);
            if ($callback) {
                return array_merge(array($first_level_key), $callback);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

How to use

```
$yourValue = "diam-mm";
$array_keymap = array_recursive_search_key_map($yourValue, $yourArray);
var_dump($array_keymap);
```

Output

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => PropertyType
    [2] => Name
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).